# How to put global key _keyForm inside my TextFormField as it is separated by different widget

Tags: validation, flutter, textfield

I am trying to figure out how to put my global _formKey inside my form field as it is separated by different widget. I try putting they key in both widget, but it detected as 2 different widget is using the same global key. This is my code which i have trying to fix. I hope i can get some help with this form validation. Thank you.

```
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  //text field state
  String username = '';
  String password = '';
  String error ='';

  bool _rememberMe = false;

  Widget _buildUsernameTF() {
   return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: <Widget>[
      Text(
       'Username',
         style: kLabelStyle,
       ),
    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
      height: 60.0,
        child: TextFormField(
        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter the username' : null,
        onChanged: (val){
          setState(() => username = val);
        }, 
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.person,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          hintText: 'Enter your username',
          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);}

  Widget _buildPasswordTF() {
  return Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Password',
      style: kLabelStyle,
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
      height: 60.0,
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: (val) => val.length < 8 ? 'Enter the password at least 8 chars long' : null,
        onChanged: (val){
          setState(() => password = val);
        },
        obscureText: true,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.lock,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          hintText: 'Enter your Password',
          hintStyle: kHintTextStyle,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormKey` is used for a single `Form()` only. Please read about [Form Field Validation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation) here. The use case is this, that `Form class` should be having only single `_formKey` and the all the `TextFields()` will be mentioned in the `child` of the `Form`. Please see the represenation

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(
  key: _formKey,
  // Here you can get your child/children on the basis of your requirements
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
        //Mention both of your TextFields here
    ]
  )
)
```

So your code should be like this, to be workable.

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

Form(
  key: _formKey,
  // Here you can get your child/children on the basis of your requirements
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
        _buildUsernameTF(),
        _buildPasswordTF()
    ]
  )
)
```

I hope that, you know now how to do the validation on Button click. But it in mentioned in the link too, so don't worry. Rest, this will help you surely. Keep learning.

Comment: Great @vaineaurelius.